# What is the most memory efficient way to initialize a list before a loop in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, initialization, memory-efficient

I am wondering what the most memory efficient way to initialize a list is in R if that list is going to be used in a loop to store results.  I know that growing an object in a loop can cause a serious hit in computational efficiency so I am trying to avoid that as much as possible.

My problem is as follows.  I have several groups of data that I want to process individually. The gist of my code is I have a loop that runs through each group one at a time, does some t-tests, and then returns only the statistically significant results (thus variable length results for each group).  So far I am initializing a list of `length(groups)` to store the results of each iteration.

My main question is how I should be initializing the list so that the object is not grown in the loop.

- Is it good enough to do `list = vector(mode = "list", length=length(groups))` for the initialization?

  - I am skeptical about this because it just creates a list of `length(groups)` but each entry is equal to `NULL`.  My concern is that during each iteration of the loop when I go to store data into the list, it is going to recopy the object each time as the entry goes from `NULL` to my results vector, in which case initializing the list doesn't really do much good.  I don't know how the internals of a `list` work, however, so it is possible that it just stores the reference to the vector being stored in the list, meaning recopying is not necessary.
- The other option would be to initialize each element of the list to a vector of the maximum possible length the results could have.

  - This is not a big issue as the maximum number of possible valid results is known.  If I took this approach I would just overwrite each vector with the results vector within the loop.  Since the maximum amount of memory would already be reserved hopefully no recopying/growth would occur.  I don't want to take this approach, however, if it is not necessary and the first option above is good enough.

Below is some psuedo code describing my problem

```
#initialize variables
results = vector(mode="list", length=length(groups)) #the line of code in question
y=1
tTests = vector(length = length(singleGroup))    

#perform analysis on each group in groups
for(group in groups)
{
  #returns a vector of p values with one entry per element in group
  tTests = tTestFunction(group) 
  results[[y]] = tTests<=0.05
  y=y+1
}
```

Comment: I think an overwhelming majority would say that yes, `vector("list", length(groups))` is the way the result list should be initialized.  The question's a bit broad.

Comment: It's easy enough to test both your ideas with a toy example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work, so it is a bad example. Consider this:

```
x <- vector("list", length = 4)
tracemem(x)  ## trace memory copies of "x"
for (i in 1:4) x[[i]] <- rnorm(4)
```

No extra copy of `x` is made during update. So there is nothing to worry.

As suggested by @lmo, even if you use `x <- list()` to initialize this list, no memory copy will be incurred, either.

---

**Comment**

The aim of my answer, is to refer you to the use of `tracemem`, when you want to trace (possible) memory copies made during code execution. Had you known this function, you would not ask us here.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37614496/4891738) is my other answer made, related to using `tracemem`. It is in a different context, though. There, you can see what `tracemem` would return when memory copies are made.

Comment: The code doesn't work because it is psuedo code, as stated in my question.  I included it to show the logical framework of what I was attempting to accomplish, not to give a working example (since this is just a small part of a complicated code chunk).  And thank you for the answer, that `tracemem` seems pretty handy.

Comment: `tracemem()` is not reporting memory reallocation, I don't know why; use `.Internal(inspect(x))` to see that the outer vector is re-allocated on each assignment (the `@...` in the first line of output is the memory address of the list; somehow, it 'has' to be, because the original allocation wasn't big enough). And while individual elements aren't duplicated, they are copied into the list, with 1 copy for i = 2, 2 copies for i = 3, ... and about n (n - 1) / 2 copies (quadratic scaling) overall.

Comment: `inspect()` is a C-level function that summarizes information about each symbol; there is more information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359940/r-programming-vector-a1-2-avoid-copying-the-whole-vector/18361181#18361181 and elsewhere in StackOverflow.