# making a triangular (or generally a square) matrix symmetirc

Tags: c, r, performance, matrix

I am trying to create a symmetrical matrix from a lower triangular matrix in R.

In a previous Q & A ([Convert upper triangular part of a matrix to symmetric matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613345/r-convert-upper-triangular-part-of-a-matrix-to-symmetric-matrix)) user [李哲源](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4891738/%e6%9d%8e%e5%93%b2%e6%ba%90?tab=profile) said that for large matrices this shouldn't be done in R and proposed a solution in C. But I don't understand C and have never used for example `Rccp` before so don't know how to interpret the answer. Yet it is obvious that the C code there generates random numbers (`rnorm`) which I don't want. **I want to put in a square matrix and get out a symmetric matrix.**

For a given square matrix `A` that has data in its lower triangle, how would I create a symmetric matrix efficiently in C and use it in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quickly adapted from the `dist2mat` function in [as.matrix on a distance object is extremely slow; how to make it faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51707582/4891738).

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('NumericMatrix Mat2Sym(NumericMatrix A, bool up2lo, int bf) {

  IntegerVector dim = A.attr("dim");
  size_t n = (size_t)dim[0], m = (size_t)dim[1];
  if (n != m) stop("A is not a square matrix!");

  /* use pointers */
  size_t j, i, jj, ni, nj;
  double *A_jj, *A_ij, *A_ji, *col, *row, *end;

  /* cache blocking factor */
  size_t b = (size_t)bf;

  /* copy lower triangular to upper triangular; cache blocking applied */
  for (j = 0; j < n; j += b) {
    nj = n - j; if (nj > b) nj = b;
    /* diagonal block has size nj x nj */
    A_jj = &A(j, j);
    for (jj = nj - 1; jj > 0; jj--, A_jj += n + 1) {
      /* copy a column segment to a row segment (or vise versa) */
      col = A_jj + 1; row = A_jj + n;
      for (end = col + jj; col < end; col++, row += n) {
        if (up2lo) *col = *row; else *row = *col;
        }
      }
    /* off-diagonal blocks */
    for (i = j + nj; i < n; i += b) {
      ni = n - i; if (ni > b) ni = b;
      /* off-diagonal block has size ni x nj */
      A_ij = &A(i, j); A_ji = &A(j, i);
      for (jj = 0; jj < nj; jj++) {
        /* copy a column segment to a row segment (or vise versa) */
        col = A_ij + jj * n; row = A_ji + jj;
        for (end = col + ni; col < end; col++, row += n) {
          if (up2lo) *col = *row; else *row = *col;
          }
        }
      }
    }

  return A;
  }')
```

For a square matrix `A`, this function `Mat2Sym` copies its lower triangular part (with transposition) into its upper triangular part to make it symmetric if `up2lo = FALSE`, and vise versa if `up2lo = TRUE`.

Note that the function **overwrites** `A` without using extra memory. To retain the input matrix and create a new output matrix, pass `A + 0` not `A` into the function.

```
## an arbitrary asymmetric square matrix
set.seed(0)
A <- matrix(runif(25), 5)
#          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.8966972 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452
#[2,] 0.2655087 0.8983897 0.20597457 0.4976992 0.9347052
#[3,] 0.3721239 0.9446753 0.17655675 0.7176185 0.2121425
#[4,] 0.5728534 0.6607978 0.68702285 0.9919061 0.6516738
#[5,] 0.9082078 0.6291140 0.38410372 0.3800352 0.1255551
```

```
## lower triangular to upper triangular; don't overwrite
B <- Mat2Sym(A + 0, up2lo = FALSE, 128)
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078
#[2,] 0.2655087 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140
#[3,] 0.3721239 0.9446753 0.1765568 0.6870228 0.3841037
#[4,] 0.5728534 0.6607978 0.6870228 0.9919061 0.3800352
#[5,] 0.9082078 0.6291140 0.3841037 0.3800352 0.1255551

## A is unchanged
A
#          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.8966972 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452
#[2,] 0.2655087 0.8983897 0.20597457 0.4976992 0.9347052
#[3,] 0.3721239 0.9446753 0.17655675 0.7176185 0.2121425
#[4,] 0.5728534 0.6607978 0.68702285 0.9919061 0.6516738
#[5,] 0.9082078 0.6291140 0.38410372 0.3800352 0.1255551
```

```
## upper triangular to lower triangular; overwrite
D <- Mat2Sym(A, up2lo = TRUE, 128)
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.89669720 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452
#[2,] 0.20168193 0.8983897 0.20597457 0.4976992 0.9347052
#[3,] 0.06178627 0.2059746 0.17655675 0.7176185 0.2121425
#[4,] 0.76984142 0.4976992 0.71761851 0.9919061 0.6516738
#[5,] 0.77744522 0.9347052 0.21214252 0.6516738 0.1255551

## A has been changed; D and A are aliased in memory
A
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.89669720 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452
#[2,] 0.20168193 0.8983897 0.20597457 0.4976992 0.9347052
#[3,] 0.06178627 0.2059746 0.17655675 0.7176185 0.2121425
#[4,] 0.76984142 0.4976992 0.71761851 0.9919061 0.6516738
#[5,] 0.77744522 0.9347052 0.21214252 0.6516738 0.1255551
```

---

**On the use of `Matrix` package**

`Matrix` is particularly useful for sparse matrices. For compatibility it also defines some classes like "dgeMatrix", "dtrMatrix", "dtpMatrix", "dsyMatrix", "dspMatrix" for dense matrices.

Given a square matrix `A`, the `Matrix` way to make it symmetric is the following.

```
set.seed(0)
A <- matrix(runif(25), 5)
#          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.8966972 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452
#[2,] 0.2655087 0.8983897 0.20597457 0.4976992 0.9347052
#[3,] 0.3721239 0.9446753 0.17655675 0.7176185 0.2121425
#[4,] 0.5728534 0.6607978 0.68702285 0.9919061 0.6516738
#[5,] 0.9082078 0.6291140 0.38410372 0.3800352 0.1255551

## equivalent to: Mat2Sym(A + 0, TRUE, 128)
new("dsyMatrix", x = base::c(A), Dim = dim(A), uplo = "U")
#5 x 5 Matrix of class "dsyMatrix"
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.89669720 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452
#[2,] 0.20168193 0.8983897 0.20597457 0.4976992 0.9347052
#[3,] 0.06178627 0.2059746 0.17655675 0.7176185 0.2121425
#[4,] 0.76984142 0.4976992 0.71761851 0.9919061 0.6516738
#[5,] 0.77744522 0.9347052 0.21214252 0.6516738 0.1255551

## equivalent to: Mat2Sym(A + 0, FALSE, 128)
new("dsyMatrix", x = base::c(A), Dim = dim(A), uplo = "L")
#5 x 5 Matrix of class "dsyMatrix"
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078
#[2,] 0.2655087 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140
#[3,] 0.3721239 0.9446753 0.1765568 0.6870228 0.3841037
#[4,] 0.5728534 0.6607978 0.6870228 0.9919061 0.3800352
#[5,] 0.9082078 0.6291140 0.3841037 0.3800352 0.1255551
```

`Matrix` method is sub-optimal for three reasons:

1. It requires passing `x` slot as a numeric vector, so we have to do `base::c(A)` which essentially creates a copy of the matrix in RAM;
2. It can not do in-place modification, so a new matrix copy is created as the output matrix;
3. It does not do cache blocking when doing transposed copying.

Here is a quick comparison:

```
library(bench)
A <- matrix(runif(5000 * 5000), 5000)
bench::mark("Mat2Sym" = Mat2Sym(A, FALSE, 128),
            "Matrix" = new("dsyMatrix", x = base::c(A), Dim = dim(A), uplo = "L"),
            check = FALSE)
#  expression      min     mean   median     max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr
#  <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>
#1 Mat2Sym      56.8ms   57.7ms   57.4ms  59.4ms     17.3     2.48KB     0     9
#2 Matrix      334.3ms  337.4ms  337.4ms 340.6ms      2.96  190.74MB     2     2
```

Note how fast `Mat2Sym` is. Also no memory allocation is made in "overwriting" mode.

[As G. Grothendieck mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52573116/4891738), we can also use "dspMatrix".

```
set.seed(0)
A <- matrix(runif(25), 5)
#          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.8966972 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452
#[2,] 0.2655087 0.8983897 0.20597457 0.4976992 0.9347052
#[3,] 0.3721239 0.9446753 0.17655675 0.7176185 0.2121425
#[4,] 0.5728534 0.6607978 0.68702285 0.9919061 0.6516738
#[5,] 0.9082078 0.6291140 0.38410372 0.3800352 0.1255551

## equivalent to: Mat2Sym(A + 0, TRUE, 128)
new("dspMatrix", x = A[upper.tri(A, TRUE)], Dim = dim(A), uplo = "U")
#5 x 5 Matrix of class "dspMatrix"
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.89669720 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452
#[2,] 0.20168193 0.8983897 0.20597457 0.4976992 0.9347052
#[3,] 0.06178627 0.2059746 0.17655675 0.7176185 0.2121425
#[4,] 0.76984142 0.4976992 0.71761851 0.9919061 0.6516738
#[5,] 0.77744522 0.9347052 0.21214252 0.6516738 0.1255551

## equivalent to: Mat2Sym(A + 0, FALSE, 128)
new("dspMatrix", x = A[lower.tri(A, TRUE)], Dim = dim(A), uplo = "L")
#5 x 5 Matrix of class "dspMatrix"
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078
#[2,] 0.2655087 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140
#[3,] 0.3721239 0.9446753 0.1765568 0.6870228 0.3841037
#[4,] 0.5728534 0.6607978 0.6870228 0.9919061 0.3800352
#[5,] 0.9082078 0.6291140 0.3841037 0.3800352 0.1255551
```

Again, `Matrix` is method is sub-optimal, due to the use of `upper.tri` or `lower.tri`.

```
library(bench)
A <- matrix(runif(5000 * 5000), 5000)
bench::mark("Mat2Sym" = Mat2Sym(A, FALSE, 128),
            "Matrix" = new("dspMatrix", x = A[lower.tri(A, TRUE)], Dim = dim(A),
                           uplo = "L"),
            check = FALSE)
#  expression      min     mean   median     max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr
#  <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>
#1 Mat2Sym      56.5ms   57.9ms     58ms  58.7ms     17.3     2.48KB     0     9
#2 Matrix      934.7ms  934.7ms    935ms 934.7ms      1.07  524.55MB     2     1
```

In particular, we see that using "dspMatrix" is even less efficient that using "dsyMatrix".

Answer (score 2):

Before making possibly premature optimizations with C/C++ check whether a dense matrix

```
A + t(A)
```

is sufficient (assuming A's only nonzero elements are below the diagonal or above it.

Also, if memory is the problem then the Matrix package has the packed symmetric class `dspMatrix` which can be created like this:

```
library(Matrix)

A <- matrix(c(0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0), 3) # dense lower triangular test input
dspA <- as(A + t(A), "dspMatrix")
```

giving:

```
> str(dspA)
Formal class 'dspMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 5 slots
  ..@ x       : num [1:6] 0 2 0 3 4 0   <- only 6 elements stored, not 9
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 3 3
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ uplo    : chr "U"
  ..@ factors : list()
```

or one can create it directly from the upper triangular part:

```
# use upper triangular part since we already created dspA that way
tA <- t(A)
dspA2 <- new("dspMatrix", Dim = as.integer(c(3,3)), 
  x = tA[upper.tri(tA, diag = TRUE)])

identical(dspA, dspA2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: That is a good idea I had forgotten about sparse matrices. However, I was interested in a Cpp solution because I was having speed problems.